# jQuery Conditional

Tags: jquery

I simply need to apply a css style to a particular class that meets my criteria.  With a simple array I'm able to do this:

```
var ins = document.getElementsByClassName('ins');
for(var i = 0; i < ins.length; i++) {
if(ins.item(i).attributes[0].value == "ins right" || ins.item(i).attributes[0].value == "ins left") 
    ins[i].style.width = "120px"; //applies the width to left and right only
}
```

What is the equivalent when using jQuery? 
*(unfortunately this applies the width to all three elements)*

```
if($('.ins').is('.left, .right'))
    $('.ins').css('width','120px');
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="ins right">
      <p>This is heading 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ins left">
      <p>This is heading 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ins center">
      <p>This is heading 2 This is heading 2 This is heading 2 This is heading 2 This is heading 2 This is heading 2 This is heading 2 This is heading 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a note you can do conditional checks for classes using jQuery's hasClass. `if ( $('element').hasClass('left')) { ... }` http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
$('.ins.left, .ins.right').css('width','120px');
```

Comment: Thanks!  Apparently I was overcomplicating and over-thinking things. jQuery is very powerful and convenient!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.ins.left, .ins.right').css('width','120px');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ins.left, .ins.right").css({/*...*/})
```

Answer (score 1):

very simple, try the following:

```
$('.ins.right, .ins.left').css('width','120px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original way used a loop that went through each individual element. You need to have jquery do the same thing.

Try this, it uses implicit iteration.

```
$(".ins").filter(".left,.right").css('width','120px');
```